# PhoneGap project: broken in Android, working in iOS. ( Gradle Error in Terminal -- Broken Pipe in Android Studio)

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm attempting a simple HelloWorld with PhoneGap. I'm new to setting up the dependencies and unclear if the error is in my setup. The same project works in iOS and does not in Android.

I've taken these steps:

1. Installed Java7 JDK
2. Installed Android Studio 2.1.2
3. Installed Android SDKs:

   Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK: Selected from Android 6.X(N) through Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)
4. Set path to enable Android SDK: `sudo nano /etc/paths`

   `/Users/(username)/Library/Android/sdk`
   `/Users/(username)/Library/Android/sdk/tools`
5. created a `phoneGap` app - for brevity, posting link instead of steps:
   http://phonegap.com/getstarted/

Result:

- Successfully ran PhoneGap iOS project w/Xcode emulator.
- Successfully ran PhoneGap iOS project w/iPhone via PhoneGap mobile app.
- Unsuccessful in running Android project with an emulator (Genymotion) or device plugged in.

Error in terminal:

```
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/Christina/Desktop/phoneGapHelloWorld/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/Christina/Desktop/phoneGapHelloWorld/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

error in Android Studio's event log:

```
8:58:21 AM Adb connection Error:EOF
8:58:21 AM Connection attempts: 1
8:58:22 AM Connection attempts: 2
8:58:23 AM Connection attempts: 3
8:58:30 AM Broken pipe
           java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
           at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
           at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
           at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
           at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
           at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
           at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:361)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:65)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMonitor... (show balloon)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an oversight. I needed to:

```
npm install cordova -g
```